# Perspective Projection, Canonical Viewing Volume

Tags: opengl, perspective, frustum

```
Vector3d nearC(0,0,0 -w);
Vector3d farC(0,0,0-x);
double width = y/2;
double height = z/2;
double angleOfHeight = atan(height/w);
double angleOfWidth = atan(width/w);
double adjustedHeight = tan(angleOfHeight) * x;
double adjustedWidth = tan(angleOfWidth) * x;

nearC[0] - width, nearC[1] - height, nearC[2]
nearC[0] - width, nearC[1] + height, nearC[2]
nearC[0] + width, nearC[1] + height, nearC[2]
nearC[0] + width, nearC[1] - height, nearC[2]
farC[0] - adjustedWidth, farC[1] - adjustedHeight, farC[2]
farC[0] - adjustedWidth, farC[1] + adjustedHeight, farC[2]
farC[0] + adjustedWidth, farC[1] + adjustedHeight, farC[2]
farC[0] + adjustedWidth, farC[1] - adjustedHeight, farC[2]
```

Above is my frustum in view coordinates. View Matrix is:

```
 0   0  -1   0
 0   1   0  -1
 1   0   0 -10
 0   0   0   1
```

All of it is right, we have a sheet.

I can't for the life of me figure how to get that frustum in canonical viewing volume. I've run through every perspective projection I could find. Current is this:

```
        s,        0,                      0,                     0,
        0,        s,                      0,                     0,
        0,        0,             -(f+ne)/(f-ne),            2*f*ne/(f-ne),
        0,        0,                      1,                     0;
```

double s = 1/tan(angleOfView * 0.5 * M_PI / 180);

I'm missing a step or something, right? Or a few steps?

Sorry to sound so hopeless now, been spinning wheels a while on this.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: its unclear what you want to achieve.... and where the problem is try to describe your problem a bit more

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something like this: https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/projection-matrices-what-you-need-to-know-first Mapping a viewing frustum to that -1,1 canonical view. But I just can't manage it haha.

Comment: what exactly is known? your first code/table is a mess.

Comment: I have the translation from world coordinates to viewing coordinates. That's from the first block, which gives the 8 corners of the frustum. The matrix beneath that is the translation from world coordinates to viewing coordinates. Now I'm trying to get those 8 corners of the frustum into a -1,1 box. w is the distance to the far pane. x is the distance to the near pane. Calculations beneath all that are trig to get the frustum. **Sorry x is far, w is near.

Comment: Basically I've managed the trig and the first translation from world coordinates to viewing coordinates but every other matrix has eluded me. Can't work the orthogonal, can't work the canonical viewing volume.

Comment: are you sure your 8 points form frustrum? I would start with projection and only then go for view matrix

Answer (score 2):

Lest start with the perspective projection. The common way in old GL is to use [`gluPerspective`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24009436/2521214).

for that we need `znear,zfar,FOV` and aspect ratio of view. For more info see:

- [Calculating the perspective projection matrix according to the view plane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30422413/2521214)

  I am used to use **FOVx** (viewing angle in `x` axis). To compute that you need to look at your frustrum from above looking at xz plane (in camera space):

  [image: frustrum XY plane]

  so:

  ```
  tan(FOVx/2) = znear_width / 2*focal_length
  FOVx = 2*atan(znear_width / 2*focal_length)
  ```

  the focal length can be computed by computing the intersection of frustrum edge lines. Or by using triangle similarity. The second is easier to write:

  ```
  zfar_width/2*(|zfar-znear|+focal_length) = znear_width/2*(focal_length)
  zfar_width/(|zfar-znear|+focal_length) = znear_width/(focal_length)
  focal_length = (|zfar-znear|+focal_length)*znear_width/zfar_width
  focal_length - focal_length*znear_width/zfar_width = |zfar-znear|*znear_width/zfar_width 
  focal_length*(1-(znear_width/zfar_width)) = |zfar-znear|*znear_width/zfar_width 
  focal_length = (|zfar-znear|*znear_width/zfar_width) / (1-(znear_width/zfar_width))
  ```

  and that is all we need so:

  ```
  focal_length = (|zfar-znear|*znear_width/zfar_width) / (1-(znear_width/zfar_width))
  FOVx = 2*atan(znear_width / 2*focal_length)        
  FOVx*=180.0/M_PI; // convert to degrees
  aspect=znear_width/znear_height;
  gluPerspective(FOVx/aspect,aspect,znear,zfar);
  ```

  just be aware of that `|zfar-znear|` is perpendicular distance between the planes !!! So if you do not have axis aligned ones then you need to compute that using dot product and normal ...

Comment: Thanks very much buddy. I'll try this out now. Btw you seem so cool haha.

Comment: Hello again, buddy, I got that out. Well, it was what I had already really, only I had it all done out myself. But now how do I get the canonical view volume? Dunno will you get this haha.

Comment: @Sean You just multiply the modelview and projection matrices together ... where modelview represents transformation from your rendered model space into view space.. From the stuff you got in your question it looks like your frustrum is axis aligned so its just matter of translating along z axis. Beware gluPerspective is looking in `-Z` direction so maybe even rotate by 180deg or flip/mirror ....